# Stack Navigator Works On Android But iOS Broken

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, stack-navigator

Our React Native Project, uses react-navigation Stack navigator. It perfectly running in Android but in ios it gives an error which "Raw Text must be wrapped in an explicit " When we try to navigate between Page.

In ios only first page loading. For example, Default 'Main Page' is the first page in order so android and ios emulator both open the first page. Then if we try to navigate between them in android navigaton works but in ios we  get "Raw text Error".

And if we change firs page of stack navigator ios also loaded  first page correctly but not navigate between them as expected.

We think navigated pages may be problem, so we create a blank page and navigate to there, but issue still continue in iOS.

I am really glad to hear suggestions.

This is how we navigate between pages:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileSayfa');
```

This is our  index.android.js and also index.android.ios:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import {StackNavigator,DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import LoginPage from "./src/pages/login-page/login-page";
import MainPage from "./src/pages/main-page/main-page";
import MekanAraSonuc from "./src/pages/MekanAra/MekanAraSonuc";
import MekanAra from "./src/pages/main-page/tabs/mekan_ara";
import NewsTab from "./src/pages/main-page/tabs/news-tab";
import StartPage from "./src/pages/start-page/start-page";
import AllMekan from "./src/pages/AllMekan/AllMekan";
import MekanSayfa from "./src/pages/MekanSayfa/MekanSayfa";
import RezervasyonSayfa from "./src/pages/MekanSayfa/RezervasyonSayfa";
import FirsatSayfa from "./src/pages/MekanSayfa/FirsatSayfa";
import EtkinlikSayfa from "./src/pages/MekanSayfa/EtkinlikSayfa";
import ProfileSayfa from "./src/pages/MekanSayfa/ProfileSayfa";
import EtkinlikSonuc from "./src/pages/AllMekan/EtkinlikSonuc";
import FirsatlarSonuc from "./src/pages/AllMekan/FirsatSonuc";
import IconME from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Drawer from "./src/pages/MyComponents/Drawer";
import SearchForm from "./src/pages/MyComponents/SearchForm";
import RezervasyonForm from "./src/pages/Forms/RezervasyonForm";
import FirsatForm from "./src/pages/Forms/FirsatForm";
import CalendarListView from "./src/pages/Forms/CalendarListView";


export default class moreAwesome extends Component {
  render() {

        return (
            <LoginApp

                ref={nav => {
                    this.navigator = nav;

                }}
            />
        );
  }
}

const LoginApp = StackNavigator({


            MainPage: {
              screen: MainPage,

            },
            LoginPage: { screen: LoginPage },
            MekanAraSonuc:{screen:MekanAraSonuc},
            MekanAra:{screen:MekanAra},
            NewsTab:{screen:NewsTab},
            AllMekan:{screen:AllMekan},
            MekanSayfa:{screen:MekanSayfa},
            FirsatSayfa:{screen:FirsatSayfa},
            EtkinlikSayfa:{screen:EtkinlikSayfa},
            EtkinlikSonuc:{screen:EtkinlikSonuc},
            FirsatlarSonuc:{screen:FirsatlarSonuc},
            ProfileSayfa:{screen:ProfileSayfa},
            RezervasyonSayfa:{screen:RezervasyonSayfa},
            SearchForm:{screen:SearchForm},
            RezervasyonForm:{screen:RezervasyonForm},
            FirsatForm:{screen:FirsatForm},
            CalendarListView:{screen:CalendarListView},

        });

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myproje', () => moreAwesome);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly, when you create  static Navigation Options  for an page, "title" can be empty string in Android but not on iOS.
When we change this,

```js
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                title: '',
                };
            };
```

To this:

When we change this,

```js
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: ' ',
            };
        };
```

And Also be careful intial page gives this error not target page!